# Vue.js - Pinia Store - Fetch to Server - returns complete store

Tags: fetch, vuejs3, user-input, store, pinia

I have a little Vue.js SPA with a contact form with 3 inputs to enter name, email and message. All this is saved by 'action' in the Pinia store, together with some other information:

```
state: () =>({
      treks: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name":"Annapurna Basecamp Trek",
          "length":"8 days",
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name":"Everest Basecamp Trek",
          "length":"10 days",
      },
      ],
      userName: "",
      userEmail: "",
      userText: "",
      rgbValue: [255, 0, 0],
      emailRegEx: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ 

    }),
```

Now I am sending this to the backend server via a fetch:

```
let postOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers().append('content-type', 'application/json'), // Media Type Req
            body: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName, userEmail: userEmail, userText: userText })
        }

        let responsePrisma = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:7050/receiveUserData`, postOptions)
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('SERVER RESPONSE: ', res)
                    resolve(res)
                    reject('ERROR')
                })
        })
```

What I get at the server for userName, userEmail and userText now is the complete store state for every data object I want to send:

```
{
  userName: {
    _object: {
      treks: [Array],
      userName: 'TestName',
      userEmail: 'TestEmail@email.com',
      userText: 'TestMessage',
      rgbValue: [Array],
      emailRegEx: {}
    },
    _key: 'userName',
    __v_isRef: true
  },
  userEmail: {
    _object: {
      treks: [Array],
      userName: 'TestName',
      userEmail: 'TestEmail@email.com',
      userText: 'TestMessage',
      rgbValue: [Array],
      emailRegEx: {}
    },
    _key: 'userEmail',
    __v_isRef: true
  },
  userText: {
    _object: {
      treks: [Array],
      userName: 'TestName',
      userEmail: 'TestEmail@email.com',
      userText: 'TestMessage',
      rgbValue: [Array],
      emailRegEx: {}
    },
    _key: 'userText',
    __v_isRef: true
  }
}
```

How can I manage just to get back the data I want to send and not the complete store 3 times?

Comment: You can try switching from Composition API to Objects API. Or perform the fetch inside your Vue component rather than the Pinia store.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really only want to use the Composition as it is newer and use the Pinia store instead of Vuex for personal preference :). But should this be like that in general, guess there is a programmatic solution but could not find anything on that so far...

Comment: Using something just because it is newer is not always the best decision but at least Vue offers us a choice. I would be very upset if they remove the Options API.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry now got this solved, just if anyone should have the same problem. Use getter in Pinia Store, instead of the actions :)

```
getters: {
  returnStateOfuserName: (state) =>{
    return state.userName
  },
  returnStateOfuserEmail: (state) =>{
    return state.userEmail
  },
  returnStateOfuserText: (state) =>{
    return state.userText
  }

  }
```

AND

```
const trekStore = useTreksStore()
   
    const userName = trekStore.returnStateOfuserName
    const userEmail = trekStore.returnStateOfuserEmail
    const userText = trekStore.returnStateOfuserText
```